# How come "flutter create ." adds desktop support?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I created a Flutter project within Android Studio, and then later found out that Flutter supports desktop. After searching the web, I did things like switching to "dev", adding config for desktop, etc. But when I tried to ran it, I got "No Windows desktop project configured", even though I enabled the configuration.

The [documentation page](https://flutter.dev/desktop#add-desktop-support-to-an-existing-flutter-app) had

> To add desktop support to an existing Flutter project, run the following command in a terminal from the root project directory:

```
flutter create .
```

> This adds the necessary desktop files and directories to your existing Flutter project.

But what is the meaning of `.`? How come that `.` means "adding desktop support"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The command to add desktop support are those one:

```
 flutter config --enable-windows-desktop
 flutter config --enable-macos-desktop
 flutter config --enable-linux-desktop
```

Once you used them, you change your flutter config.

Then, the usage of `flutter create .` simply mean "Create a new flutter project in my current folder".
If you're already in a Flutter project, it will just "recreate" your project by adding the new support for Desktop since you specify in your flutter config.

Answer (score 5):

1. `flutter config --enable-[windows,linux,macos]-desktop`
2. `flutter create .`

if there is some error with second command, remove `-` sign from parent folder name, and run this command:

```
flutter create --org com.example.myapp .
```

Answer (score 3):

```
flutter create --platforms=windows,macos,linux .
```

you can use this line instead

Answer (score 2):

Run this command it works fine for me.

run

**flutter config --enable-windows-desktop**

then run

**flutter create .**

if flutter create . generate error, probably there is ***-*** in your root project directory.

for example it will generate error if your project is like below

**Alewa-Stock**

to work it fine rename your project directory like below

**alewa_stock**

then run the following command

**flutter create --platforms=windows --org=com.alewa.store .**

*

> NB: Please change the name according to your preference.

- 